# What Visual C++ setting/option/flag is the counterpart of -ansi -pedantic in g++

Tags: c++

I have a C++ codebase, and I am porting from Visual Studio to g++, which should I set in Visual Studio so that build errors in gcc are reduced? With g++ this is achieved by -ansi -pedantic.

Comment: -pedantic is exactly what it says; and therefore largely pointless.  I'd avoid it and simply set up an automated build that uses both compilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [/Za](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx).

Comment: Had totally forgotten about that switch.  TBH, though, GCC is still a HELL of a lot more pedantic :)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably set the highest warning level /W4 and also disable the MS specific language extensions, /Za.  Also check that you're using the for loop scope option /Zc:forScope

Comment: /Zc:forScope is the default. There is no need to specify this switch explicitly.

Comment: It's the default for new projects, but if you have a project that was started in VS2003 and then upgraded through 2005 and/or 2008 then it will be switched off, so it's worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

The only real way to do this is to compile under VStudio AND under GCC.  GCC *can be* a lot more pedantic than VStudio :)

Comment: @Goz:"GCC can be a lot more pedantic than VStudio" -- and vice versa. They're pedantic about different things.